# JavaScript onclick visible / hidden div - How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, hidden, visible

I have created a map on my website, which should then become interactive.

I have created a `div` container and placed it exactly where there is a city in which we have a company.

With `:hover` per CSS, I have created infoboxes to store the information.

I want whenever I click on any `div`, it clicks the information of the selected place.

Here my CSS:

```
#information_city 
visibility: hidden;
width: 540px;
height: 335px;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 50px;
margin-left: -200px;
border: 1px solid # 999;
filter: alpha (opacity = 90);
transition: opacity 1.5s;


#information_city
  visibility: visible;
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "city">
<div id = "information_city">
</ Div>
</ Div>
```

Now I want the infobox per click to open with a toggle.

It is important that the inner `div` folder `information_city` opens when the city is clicked.

How can I solve this the best?

Comment: please insert code as snippet thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.city {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative; 
}

.information_city {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 540px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid # 999;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in, visibility 1.5s ease-in;
}
.city.show .information_city {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="city">
        <p>Click on city</p>
        <div class="information_city">
            <p>details</p>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="city">
        <p>Click on city</p>
        <div class="information_city">
            <p>details</p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="city">
        <p>Click on city</p>
        <div class="information_city">
            <p>details</p>
        </div>
  </div>

    <script>
var cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');

for (var i=cities.length; i--;) {
    cities[i].addEventListener('click', ToggleDetails, false);
}

function removeShow() {
  var cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');
  for (var i=cities.length; i--;) {
      cities[i].classList.remove('show');
  }
}      

function ToggleDetails() {  
     if(this.classList.contains('show')) {
       //Hide them all
        removeShow();
     } else {
       //Hide the other and show this one
       removeShow();
       this.classList.add('show');
     }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could add a class on click. And add the theming to the child of the #city div with css. When the class is added, the child div will be visible due a css transition. 
Like this for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#city {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative; 
}

#information_city {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 540px;
    height: 335px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid # 999;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in, visibility 1.5s ease-in;
}
#city.show #information_city {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="city">
        <p>Click on city</p>
        <div id="information_city">
            <p>details</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
       var city = document.getElementById('city');
       city.addEventListener('click', function(e){
           city.classList.add('show');
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The css is a bit different than in your question. I could even left some unused css out, but it's just to show how you could do it :).

Comment: THANKY YOU ! it's working ! but how i toggle this onclick to visible onclick to hidden ..  and if one infobox is visible than close this when you klick another cty to see the information city .. thank you :)

Comment: Then you should convert the id into classes first. Because id's are unique.
<div class="city"><div class="information_city"></div></div>. 
In your css, please replace the `#` with `.` to select the class elements for the theming. 
The JS can be something like this:

Comment: `var cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');

for (var i=cities.length; i--;) {
    cities[i].addEventListener('click', ToggleDetails, false);
}

function removeShow() {
  var cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');
  for (var i=cities.length; i--;) {
      cities[i].classList.remove('show');
  }
}      
      
function ToggleDetails() {  
     if(this.classList.contains('show')) {
       //Hide them all
        removeShow();
     } else {
       //Hide the other and show this one
       removeShow();
       this.classList.add('show');
     }
}
`

Comment: Wait, I will post an other example answer so it will be more clear :)

Comment: hello I use an accordion. I would like to close all open tabs if I select another tab so that only one tab is open. 
here is my js code:
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
thank you for your help

Comment: Hello Arvie can you help me with this ? :/